# Can't build a Docker container for Node app based on node:8.1 image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a container for my app based on the `node:8.1` image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.1.4


RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global ; \
    mkdir -p /home/node/app ; \
    chown -R node:node /home/node/app ; \
    chown -R node:node /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

USER node

WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Just for dev
RUN npm install mocha knex nodemon -g --quiet

# Opting for COPY over ADD as there is no need of auto extracting any compressed file
COPY . /home/node/app

RUN npm install --quiet

CMD node
```

However, when it is running `npm install --quiet` I get these messages:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/nopt/node_modules/abbrev
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/nopt
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/node_modules/delegates
```

The message repeats for every package in package.json.

And finishes with:

```
npm ERR! path /home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/node/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2017-07-12T15_51_42_496Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --quiet' returned a non-zero code: 243
```

Previously with node:7.1 I've been able to make it work without having to change the current user to `node`.

How can I make my app deploy work with the latest version of this image?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by moving the `USER` directive right below the `FROM` directive and removing the existing `node_modules` folder from the host volume.